# Centering one flex item and and aligning second item to right by any amount of px

Tags: css, flexbox

so im trying to exactly center one flex(unless anyone has other idea) item and aligning second one e.g 20px to right of my first item. My code:

```
<div className="d-flex justify-content-center border">
  <h1 className="title">Tacos</h1>
  <div className="icon"></div>
</div>
```

and this is the result [image]

As you can see, they both are centered, my goal is to put text "Tacos" in exact center and then align my icon like 20px to right. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `width: 0; white-space: nowrap;` trick.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.icon {
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="text">Tacos</div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works but if there is margin it puts the text slightly to left, so instead I used padding left and right on text and it's ok now :)